Lie Groups Homeomorphic to $\Bbb{R^n}$
Let Lie group $G$ be homeomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^n$. Does this imply its maximal compact subgroup is trivial? Thank you for the reply.

Any connected real Lie group $G$ is diffeomorphic to $K\times \mathbb R^n$ where $K$ is a maximal compact subgroup. This is a theorem of Cartan in the case where $G$ is semisimple, and may be due to Mostow in the general case perhaps?
This of course implies that if $G$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$, then its maximal compact subgroups $K$ must have the homotopy type of a point,i.e. $K$ is contractible. But the only contractible connected compact Lie group is the trivial group, hence the maximal compact subgroup of such a $G$ must be trivial.

It all makes sense. Thank you very much for the reply.

You're welcome!

I think it's due to Iwasawa in general (1950 or 1951). Mostow extended this to finitely many components. (By Cartan you mean Elie Cartan or Henri Cartan?)
